# Icons for R files not showing on Mac after latest update

Tags: r, macos, r-markdown, rstudio

Rproject:

[image]

R markdown file:

[image]

[image]

The icons for my R projects and R markdown are not appearing on my Mac. Any help?

Tried changing the view options in the system preferences but at no avail.